# Unable to integrate ElFinder in Angular project

Tags: angular, integration, elfinder

I'm trying to integrate ElFinder (https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder) in my Angular project, but I can't seem to know how to get it to work. The Readme.md doesn't provide an example on how to setup a full application that uses ElFinder, and I'm at a loss. I have downloaded the latest stable build (compressed) release, but I'm not sure how I'm supposed to be using it from my app, My guess is that I'm supposed to start a server with the contents of the unzipped folder, and then somehow (even though I don't know how) make my program "call" elfinder from wherever its server is running, at a particular point in my html so that I can get the ElFinder explorer integrated with the other elements in my page.

Does anybody know whether this is the correct approach, and how to "call" ElFinder from an HTML / .ts file?

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to integrate elfinder to angular 9, I mark the solution so that nobody has to struggle like me. Since my back-end is made up of ASP.NET Core 3.1, I installed this connector (https://github.com/gordon-matt/elFinder.NetCore), then in your angular.json file import the scripts and styles
[image]

after put this in your view : `<div id="elfinder"></div>`

put this in your component, in your ngOnInit():

```
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var myCommands = elFinder.prototype._options.commands;
                var disabled = ['callback', 'chmod', 'editor', 'netmount', 'ping', 'search', 'zipdl', 'help']; // Not yet implemented commands in elFinder.NetCore
                elFinder.prototype.i18.en.messages.TextArea = "Edit";
                var self = this;
                $.each(disabled, function (i, cmd) {
                    (self.idx = $.inArray(cmd, myCommands)) !== -1 && myCommands.splice(self.idx, 1);
                });

                var options = {
                    url: '/el-finder/file-system/connector', // Default (Local File System)
                //customData: { folder: '@Model.Folder', subFolder: '@Model.SubFolder' }, // customData passed in every request to the connector as query strings. These values are used in FileController's Index method.*@
                   
                    rememberLastDir: false, // Prevent elFinder saving in the Browser LocalStorage the last visited directory
                        commands: myCommands,
                            //lang: 'pt_BR', // elFinder supports UI and messages localization. Check the folder Content\elfinder\js\i18n for all available languages. Be sure to include the corresponding .js file(s) in the JavaScript bundle.
                            uiOptions: { // UI buttons available to the user
                    toolbar: [
                        ['back', 'forward'],
                        ['reload'],
                        ['home', 'up'],
                        ['mkdir', 'mkfile', 'upload'],
                        ['open', 'download'],
                        ['undo', 'redo'],
                        ['info'],
                        ['quicklook'],
                        ['copy', 'cut', 'paste'],
                        ['rm'],
                        ['duplicate', 'rename', 'edit'],
                        ['selectall', 'selectnone', 'selectinvert'],
                        ['view', 'sort']
                    ]
                },
                //onlyMimes: ["image", "text/plain"] // Get files of requested mime types only
                lang: 'fr', // Change language
            };
               
        });
            
        })(jQuery);
```

then finally manage your imports well and it works!

Comment: I can not find the name elFinder where did you declare it in angular?

Comment: Also where is the opening of  })(jQuery); Thank you for your help.