# Cannot find name elFinder

Tags: angular

I want to integreate elfinder in my asp.net core angular app. I am using the instruction here [Unable to integrate ElFinder in Angular project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62320015/unable-to-integrate-elfinder-in-angular-project).
In my home.component.html I have

```
<div id="elfinder"></div>
```

then in my home.component.ts in ngOnInit() I have the following code

```
  ngOnInit(): void {

    $(document).ready(function () {
      var myCommands = elFinder.prototype._options.commands;
      var disabled = ['callback', 'chmod', 'editor', 'netmount', 'ping', 'search', 'zipdl', 'help']; // Not yet implemented commands in elFinder.NetCore
      elFinder.prototype.i18.en.messages.TextArea = "Edit";
      var self = this;
      $.each(disabled, function (i, cmd) {
        (self.idx = $.inArray(cmd, myCommands)) !== -1 && myCommands.splice(self.idx, 1);
      });

      var options = {
        url: '/resources',
        rememberLastDir: false,
        uiOptions: { // UI buttons available to the user
          toolbar: [
            ['back', 'forward'],
            ['reload'],
            ['home', 'up'],
            ['mkdir', 'mkfile', 'upload'],
            ['open', 'download'],
            ['undo', 'redo'],
            ['info'],
            ['quicklook'],
            ['copy', 'cut', 'paste'],
            ['rm'],
            ['duplicate', 'rename', 'edit'],
            ['selectall', 'selectnone', 'selectinvert'],
            ['view', 'sort']
          ]
        },
        lang: 'fr', // Change language
      };

    });

  }
```

However I get the following error Cannot find name elFinder how can I resolve this problem thank you for your help.

Comment: This looks like a bad idea (jQuery and Angular is not a good combination). However, hour could try (making some assumptions here) to 1) use NgAfterViewInit instead of onInit and then as first line use const elFinder = (window as any).elFinder;

Comment: Then how can I properly integrated elfinder in angular?