# How can I get elfinder to work in angular project

Tags: angular, elfinder

I would like [elfinder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/elfinder-dotneet#demo-sites) to work with a angular project. I am unsure where to start. My backend is asp.net core So far I have create a stackbliz projet [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-u3jyej?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,package.json,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) whre I have added jquery.
Any help would be appricieded. Also I have tried to use the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62320015/unable-to-integrate-elfinder-in-angular-project) but it did not work.

Comment: if there is any npm module availble of elfinder, then install and use it

Comment: @Gopal yes there is a npm here https://www.npmjs.com/package/elfinder but I am not sure how to use it scince it has many dependency including jquery